# Optimize sql query with LIKE %var%

Tags: sql

The query runs fast on my local dev machine, but not on the webserver. Any idea to optimize this query?

```
SELECT * from mybigtable 
WHERE title LIKE %.'$var'.% AND lang='.$lang.' 
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT 6;
```

Comment: Use a trigram index: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html

Comment: Which database are you working with?

Comment: What's your the schema for the table ?

Comment: You need to provide more information about mybigtable (especially indexes). My first step would be to check if your lang field is indexed and if it's text or int foreign key. If it's not indexed than need to add it and if it's text (eg. en, de etc) than split languages into separate table and use int indexes. You could also take advantage of partitions and create separate db partitions for each language which should improve performance.

Comment: I use mysql or mariadb.

Comment: index is already set on title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use database dependent optimizations

```
MySQL>> ALTER TABLE articles ADD FULLTEXT(title);
MySQL>> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('TEXTVALUE')

MS-SQL>> SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE FREETEXT (ProductName, 'spread' )

 PgSQL>> CREATE FUNCTION fti() RETURNS opaque AS '/path/to/fti.so' LANGUAGE 'C';
PgSQL>> CREATE TABLE articles_fti (string type, id oid);

Oracle >>  CONTAINS function
```

Answer (score 0):

A query like this cannot take advantage of indexes on most database engines; you should look at your DB's free text searching capabilities.